# Do While loop - Simply add numbers

Tags: javascript

I need to prompt the user to enter a series of numbers, or the word "quit".
Then, If the user enters a number, add the new number to a running total.
And, If the user enters the word "quit" the loop should stop execution.
I cant figure what should I do here. Im a beginner. i don't know how to make it work when user enter a word quit

```js
let total = 0;
let number = 0;
do {
  total += number;
  number = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number: '));
  if (number >= 0) {
    document.writeln("<p>You entered " + number + "!</p>");
  } else {
    if (isNaN(number)) {
      number = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number: '));
      document.writeln("<p>Try again. We are looking for a number!</p>");
    }
  }
} while (number >= 0)
document.writeln("<p>The total is " + total + "</p>")
```

Comment: Just a heads up. The loop breaks if you enter a letter two times in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **break** to stop the javascript loop:

```
let total = 0;
let number = 0;
    do {
        total += number;
        text = prompt('Enter a number: ');
        if (text == "quit") {
           break;
        }
        number = parseInt(text);
        if (number >= 0) {
            document.writeln("<p>You entered " + number + "!</p>");
        } else {
            if (isNaN(number))  {
                number = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number: '));
                document.writeln("<p>Try again. We are looking for a number!</p>");
            } 
        }
    } while(number >= 0)
    document.writeln("<p>The total is " + total + "</p>")
```

Comment: wow..thank u sir.. it works.. i appreciate it a lot

Comment: No problem! Can you please mark the answer as solved? Thx!